# Java program crashes, when giving a decimal point, but works with int

Tags: java

When a user enters a whole number, the program runs smoothly, but when the user enters a number that has a decimal at the end, the program crashes.

These are the errors that I get:

```
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at BMI.main(BMI.java:11)
```

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BMI {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int height;  // declares the height variable
    int weight;  // declares the weight variable
    String getweight;
    getweight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your weight in Kilograms");  // asks user for their weight
    String getheight;
    getheight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your height in Centimeters");  // asks user for their height
    weight = Integer.parseInt(getweight);  // stores their weight
    height = Integer.parseInt(getheight);  // stores their height
    double bmi;  // declares the BMI variable
    bmi = weight / Math.pow(height / 100.0, 2.0);  // calculates the BMI
    double roundbmi;  // variable to round the BMI to make it more read-able
    roundbmi = Math.round(bmi);  // rounds the BMI
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your BMI is: " + roundbmi);  // displays the calculated and rounded BMI
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `Integer` only recognizes whole numbers.  If you want to be able to capture floating point numbers, use either `Float.parseFloat()` or `Double.parseDouble()`.

To make the answer more complete, let me give you a quick example of why `"4."`, `"4.0"`, and `"4"` are represented in two different ways.  The first two are considered floating point values (since Java will just assume you mean `4.0` regardless), and how they are represented in memory depends heavily on which datatype you use to represent them - either a `float` or a `double`.

A `float` represents `4.0` using the [single-precision floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format), whereas a `double` would represent `4.0` using the [double-precision floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).  An `int` represents the value `4` in base-2 instead (so it'd just be 2<sup>2</sup>).

Understanding how numbers are stored internally is critical and key to development, not just with Java.  In general, it's recommended to use `Double` since that gives the larger range of floating point numbers (and higher precision).

Comment: Put an if statment in there to check if there is a period. If there is than do Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat. Otherwise, it's safe to do Integer.parseInt. Something like this: if (weight.index(".") != -1) //parse float else parseInt

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer.  My teacher will not give full credit if we don't keep the height and weight as INT's.  I assume/hope she is trying to teach us this point, and will eventually go over it in class.  Either way, your answer has explained a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You're parsing `Integers`, which cannot have decimals.  Try `Double` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You are parsing the input as an integer, which cannot have a decimal point in it. You want to parse it as a Double.